# Android. HDPI icon on desktop, but MDPI icon on activity

Tags: android

When I install and run application I see on the desktop large HDPI icon, but when activity starts, I see small MDPI icon. The icons have some marks to differentiate them, so I am sure what icons I see.

**Layout:**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" 
    />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
...
```

**Icons:**

```
/drawable-mdpi/icon.png -> 48x48 px
/drawable-hdpi/icon.png -> 72x72 px
```

**Display metrics:**

```
DisplayMetrics{density=1.0, width=1280, height=752, scaledDensity=1.0, xdpi=160.15764, ydpi=160.0}
```

So, why does it take HDPI to display on desktop? And MDPI for my screens?

Comment: "And MDPI for my screens?" Do you mean in the ActionBar?

Answer (score 0):

What is the physical size of your devices screen? I have a feeling your application is simply running in a screen compatibility mode. Otherwise, perhaps your packages resources are screwed up in some way. Normally cleaning the project in Eclipse will resolve that. If its the compatibility mode check this page for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html